# Set value of model property on first hand

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a stored procedure that returns a simple list of 3 columns:

```
ItemGroup
Weight
Price
```

I have a model like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ...
    public IList<MyItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<MyItemViewModel>();

    public MyViewModel AssignItems(IEnumerable<MyItemViewModel> model)
    {
        if (model is null) 
            return this;

        ((List<MyItemViewModel>)Items).AddRange(model);
        return this;
    }
}
```

MyItemViewModel:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
{
    public string ItemGroup { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I populate the list correctly, now I want to add some properties to `MyItemViewModel` in order to have each property assigned when it's being populated, so I try to do something like:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
{
    public string ItemGroup { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    // Pseudocode
    public decimal SteelWeight { get; set; } => Weight != null ? Weight.Where(ItemGroup == "Steel"): 0
    public decimal SteelPrice { get; set; } => Price != null ? Price.Where(ItemGroup == "Steel") : 0
    public decimal DevicesWeight { get; set; } => Weight != null ? Weight.Where(ItemGroup == "Devices") : 0
    public decimal DevicesPrice { get; set; } => Price != null ? Price.Where(ItemGroup == "Devices") : 0
}
```

Now I get this error:

> Block bodies and expression bodies cannot both be provided.

So, the expected result of the new properties is to set into them the Weight and Price value where `ItemGroup` value equals to specific string. How can I achieve that?

Extra scope: I want to do that because I want to replace that properties on a html template as:

```
  var html = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync($"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}/documentTemplates/myTemplate.html");

  html = html.Replace("steelWeight".TokenizeWithBrackets(), $"{rModel.Items.SteelWeight}")
  //etc...
```

Comment: Can you show how you plan to use these properties? It seems to me they don't belong in that class but are meant as conditions for whatever the `MyItemViewModel` is used for.

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with the final scope usage @Xerillio

Comment: Is the problem the error message about block bodies vs. expression bodies, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the error you're getting is because, as it states, you can't use both the `get; set;` syntax for a property, and also use a `=>` to point to an expression. Essentially, you're defining the "get" action twice!

Go back to what you probably had to start with:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
{
    public string ItemGroup { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    //Pseudocode
    public decimal SteelWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal SteelPrice { get; set; } 
    public decimal DevicesWeight { get; set; } 
    public decimal DevicesPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now, as for fetching the values of a particular `MyItemViewModel`:

This would be a two-part operation:  first, find the `MyItemViewModel` instance you want, from the collection in `MyViewModel`, and then retrieve the particular `Weight` and `Price` you need.

The code would be something like this:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = <whatever it takes to get an instance of this>;
MyItemViewModel target = myViewModel
                            .Items
                            .SingleOrDefault(item => item.ItemGroup == "Steel");
// I'm assuming the true destination of these values is somewhere else
// and not a property of the individual MyItemViewModel instance.

var steelWeight = target?.Weight ?? 0;
var price = target?.Price ?? 0;
```

Note that the above (which was from memory) assumes that there's only one item in `myViewModel.Items` for every value of `ItemGroup`. If there's more than one, `SingleOrDefault` won't work and you'll have to use `FirstOrDefault` or some other method.

Also, I allowed for the possibility that you might have *no* items in `MyViewModel.Items` that matched "Steel".

ETA: Here's a suggestion: give the `MyViewModel` class a new method: `GetByItemGroup`:

```
public MyItemViewModel GetByItemGroup(string itemGroup) 
{
    return this.Items.SingleOrDefault(item => item.ItemGroup == itemGroup);
}
```

Then you can use it like this in your code:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = ....;
var steelItem = myViewModel.GetByItemGroup("Steel");
var devicesItem = myViewModel.GetByItemGroup("Devices");

// Actually use the data:
targetHtml = targetHtml.Replace("steel-weight", $"{steelItem?.Weight ?? 0}");
targetHtml = targetHtml.Replace("steel-price", $"{steelItem?.Price ?? 0}");
targetHtml = targetHtml.Replace("devices-weight", $"{devicesItem?.Weight ?? 0}");
... etc.
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! it gives me an start point of what can I do! Thanks